# Data Source not found in Excel (Data/From other sources/From MS Query) connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: microsoft-excel, postgresql, odbc

I set up an ODBC connection to a datamart with `c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.

I set up my Data Sources in the System DSN tab using the PostgreSQL ANSI driver.

When I go into Excel bring in the external data (Data Tab/From Other Sources/From MS Query) my connection is not listed in the box.

How can get my Data Source viewable here?

Would really like to get this resolved as I have numerous customers with the same issue.

WindowsOS ver is 7.0, Excel is from Office 10 (ver 14.0.6129.500 - 64 bit).

Comment: Is question does not fit right here. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: have you tried browsing for it?

Comment: You're using 64-bit Office but you set up a 32-bit ODBC connection. You have to set up the 64-bit ODBC connection (use the `odbcad32.exe` that's *not* in `SysWOW64`) using the 64-bit PostgreSQL ODBC driver, or use a 32-bit Excel. (Will post as answer if/when this question gets reopened and migrated; please comment here if the question gets reopened).

Answer (score 1):

You're using 64-bit Office but you set up a 32-bit ODBC connection by using `c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` instead of ``. You have to set up the 64-bit ODBC connection (use the `odbcad32.exe` that's not in `SysWOW64`) using the 64-bit PostgreSQL ODBC driver, or use a 32-bit Excel.

You may need to install a 64-bit version of psqlODBC if you don't already have one installed.

See [Microsoft KB942976](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976).